# Making urls.py file for Flask like in Django

Tags: python, flask

Maybe someone can help/explain me, how to create `urls.py` file for Flask like in Django?

- `main.py` - main project file. It includes only app runner (`app.run()`).
- `urls.py` is situated in the same directory and need to provide views
  from `views.py`.

Comment: I just want to have one file for all URL patterns. I write "like in" just for example, because a lots of users know how it looks in Django. I don't mean "as is in django". I mean only "like in". In one file. With default URLs processor.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/svieira/HipPocket (more specifically https://github.com/svieira/HipPocket/blob/master/hip_pocket/pocket.py#L114)?  Fair warning, I wrote it and it's unfinished (documentation especially).  But it does give you centralized mapping.

Comment: People should try to answer the questions, instead judging and asking whys. Who knows if he is in a team used to Django, and all of them want to keep a Django-like structure. Here is an example of how I did it: https://gist.github.com/andres-torres-marroquin/6c865181cf898968c8b0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this as is described [in the Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/lazyloading/), basically by calling `app.add_url_rule` to set your routes rather than using the decorator.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Flask documentation, this can be solved like this:

When creating the Flask app load your 'urls.py' file

```
app.register_blueprint(apps.someapp.urls.mod)
```

Then structure urls.py as following:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from apps.someapp.views import SomeView

# set method as endpoint
view = SomeView.as_view('someview')

# Create the blueprint for this app
mod = Blueprint("payment_methods", __name__, url_prefix="/someapp/", template_folder="templates")

# Add the view as route; methods like GET, POST, PUT will automatically route to class methods with parameters
mod.add_url_rule('<int:id>/', view_func=view)
```